# Query for matching IP address in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ip

I am trying to match IP addresses. The input IP address can be "`5.1.82.1`".

So, I am matching like first part of input IP address with all the IP address in database that start with `5`. My query is like following

```
SELECT     top 1   PARSENAME(ipaddress, 4) AS firstpart, ipaddress
FROM            IPs
WHERE        (Country = 'pk') AND (PARSENAME(ipaddress, 4) <= '5')
ORDER BY Expr2 DESC
```

The above query results all the IP addresses that start with `5`. Now I need to match the second part of the address which is "`1`" against the IP address range in the database. For that I will again do an "`order by`" and select the top record that is close to second part of the input IP address.

And so I will do the same for 3rd part and 4th part. But the question is how I can do it? I think I need to use a subquery. But where I will put it in my SQL statement.

**UPDATE**:
Sample data

```
from              to                  country
[5.1.82.0]       [5.1.82.255]         PK
[5.39.250.0]     [5.39.253.255]       PK
[5.39.255.0]     [5.39.255.255]       PK
```

**IMPORTANT**
In database there are ranges of IP addresses for example: `5.1.82.0` to `5.1.82.255`

Comment: show some dummy data. its hard to figure out with only description

Comment: generally IP addresses are stored as string in dadatbase, You can compare the whole IP address like ipaddress = "5.1.82.1". Moreover you can implement index on ipaddress for quicker response.

Comment: @KishorPawar In db there are ranges but not exact ip address

Comment: BTW, clever use of the PARSENAME. Is it your idea?

Comment: if you keep your IP addresses in the database so that each octet is left-padded with zeroes to three digits (i.e. '005.001.082.000') you can then simply use the BETWEEN operator.

Comment: @cha can't I just use subquery to select and match second, third, and forth part of ip address? Can you please let me know something about this how can I use sub-sub-sub query to match till forth part of ip address

Comment: @FawadAli: yes you can. I just suggested you a faster way

Comment: An even better approach would be to store the IP addresses as 4 different tinyint columns. this will provide smaller storage space and faster performance (especially if the IP would pass to the database as 4 tinyint parameters and not as a string.

Comment: @cha can you please answer it if you know? I think I should use case when in select

Answer (score 0):

I used following function for same thing.Try it and it should work for you also.

It verifies whether the IP Address of the user is between the range of IP Addresses or not. Below script will return 1, If IP Address is between the range, otherwise it return 0;

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsIPAddressInRange
(
    @IPAddress varchar(20),
    @StartRange varchar(20),
    @EndRange varchar(20)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MAXRANGE BIGINT = 256
    RETURN 
    CASE 
    WHEN PARSENAME(@IPAddress,1) + @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@IPAddress,2) + 
    @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@IPAddress ,3) + @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@IPAddress ,4)
    BETWEEN
    PARSENAME(@StartRange,1) + @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@StartRange,2) + 
    @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@StartRange ,3) + @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@StartRange ,4)
    AND
    PARSENAME(@EndRange,1) + @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@EndRange,2) + 
    @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@EndRange ,3) + @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * @MAXRANGE * PARSENAME(@EndRange ,4)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END     
END
```

**I took above function from [HERE](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/30/scripts/485/scripts/15698/sql-server-script-to-find-whether-ipaddress-is-in-between-the-range-of-addresses-or-not.aspx).**

Comment: if u want me to mark it as answer then please explain your code a bit

Comment: @FawadAli ... 1st of all i know it is not perfect ... and as i wrote i took it from somewhere on net ... having said this it actually just multiplies all the diff part of ip address so u will have final number which can b simply use to search between rage

Comment: It also not designed to handle ip version 6 addesses

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to have all IPs in a formatted type of `###.###.###.###`, then you can use it to any check you want

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.formatIP ( @ip varchar(20) )
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN RIGHT('000'+PARSENAME(@ip,4), 3) + '.' + RIGHT('000'+PARSENAME(@ip,3), 3) + '.' + RIGHT('000'+PARSENAME(@ip,2), 3) + '.' + RIGHT('000'+PARSENAME(@ip,1), 3)
END
GO
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
DECLARE @ip1 varchar(20) = '5.1.82.205', @from varchar(20) = '5.1.82.0', @to varchar(20) = '5.1.82.255'

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN dbo.formatIP(@ip1) BETWEEN dbo.formatIP(@from) AND dbo.formatIP(@to) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
```

Comment: shouldn't it be Reght('000'+PARSENAME(@ip,...),4) insteat of 3

Comment: @FawadAli Why?, you can check results by `SELECT dbo.formatIp('5.1.82.205')` ;).

Answer (score 0):

try by Converting ip address to a big integer to search in between the range like below,

```
    declare @ips table ([fromip] varchar(15), [toip] varchar(15), country varchar(5))

        insert into @ips values
        ('5.1.82.0' ,  '5.1.82.255', 'PK'),
        ('5.39.250.0' ,'5.39.253.255','PK'),
        ('5.39.255.0','5.39.255.255','PK')

        declare @ip as varchar(15) ='5.1.82.250'

        SELECT   *
        FROM    @IPs
        WHERE        (Country = 'pk') AND 
        cast(right('00'+PARSENAME(@ip, 4),3)+ right('00'+PARSENAME(@ip, 3),3)+right('00'+PARSENAME(@ip, 2),3) +right('00'+PARSENAME(@ip, 1),3) 
AS bigint) between

        cast(right('00'+PARSENAME(fromip, 4),3)+ right('00'+PARSENAME(fromip, 3),3)+right('00'+PARSENAME(fromip, 2),3) +right('00'+PARSENAME(fromip, 1),3) 
AS bigint) and 
        cast(right('00'+PARSENAME(toip, 4),3)+ right('00'+PARSENAME(toip, 3),3)+right('00'+PARSENAME(toip, 2),3) +right('00'+PARSENAME(toip, 1),3) 
AS bigint)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    <?php
    $st = '5.1.82.1';
    echo strstr($st, '.1.82.1',true)
    ?>
```

Comment: @FawadAli maybe you don't but I do.

Comment: This question was about Mysql Server, not PHP.